# Regular Expression for pattern matching

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

Could anyone help me in fix the regular expression for finding substrings which are between two @ symbols.

Example- `fghgkghfk@hello@ggjgkglgll@hello@ghfufjkfk.`

Now i want those TWO HELLO sub string to be retrieved.
Thanks in advance. 
This helps me in pattern matching while retrieving data.

Comment: `fix the regular expression` - which one you want us to fix?

Comment: Note that you will also get `ggjgkglgll` if you fetch the contents between `@`. You would have to filter that out.

Comment: For simple delimited strings you can use split("@") and use the 1 and 3 indexes.

Answer (score 2):

This will match text between `@` characters:

```
(?<=@).*?(?=@)
```

Those are look-arounds at either end (non-consuming matches) and I've use a non-greedy match between, so the match doesn't run all the way to the end of the *next* `@` surrounded match

---

If you want an elegant one-liner that extracts all such phraxes, do this:

```
String[] phrases = input.replaceAll("(^.*?@)|(@[^@]*$)", "").split("@.*?@");
```

Here's some test code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = "fghgkghfk@hello@ggjgkglgll@hello@ghfufjkfk";
    String[] phrases = input.replaceAll("(^.*?@)|(@[^@]*$)", "").split("@.*?@");
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(phrases));
}
```

Output:

```
[hello, hello]
```

Comment: Why have you used `look-behind` and `look-ahead`? They are not really needed here.

Comment: @RohitJain I think they are needed - he doesn't wants to match on text *between*, not *including* `@`

Comment: @Bohemian.. This would also work: - `@(.*?)@`, and just get the group 1.

Comment: @RohitJain good point, but technically that regex doesn't match... group 1 of that regex matches. Splitting hairs? maybe, but sometimes you want to feed the whole match into something else without having to invoke group logic on it. btw, I used your regex (minus the grouping), in my addendum, but not to match the target, but to match what's *between* the target for a call to `split()`

Comment: @sai no probs. if you think this "answers your question", please "Accept" it (by ticking the hollow tick mark to the left)

Answer (score 0):

```
    String text = "fghgkghfk@hello1@ggjgkglgll@hello2@ghfufjkfk";

    Pattern ptrn = Pattern.compile("@(\\w+)@");

    Matcher mtchr = ptrn.matcher(text);

    while(mtchr.find())
    {
        String match = mtchr.group(1);

        System.out.println("Match = <" + match + ">");
    }
```

Comment: Thanks foam.. this matched my requirement

Comment: hey am sorry... am trying to vote but i don't have sufficient voting reputation.... sure i gonna vote when i get required reputation. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

Simple regex for strings between `@`:

```
'@(.*?)@'
```

Explanation:

```
@      # Match starts at literal @
(.*?)  # Capture everything inbetween (non-greedy)
@      # Match ends at literal @
```

See it in action [here](http://rubular.com/r/9Hm4GR9e2W).